# Meaning of どんな+Noun+も where the Noun isn't a WH word?

Tags: grammar, meaning

While watching a video, I came across the quote:

> 違う！キングダムハーツはどんな闇も消し去ることのできる心―光なんだ！

For 'どんな闇も' I first thought of the literal translation 'also what kind of darkness', but this made no sense in the context since it would add a question in a declarative statement.

My second thought was 'any darkness' to give the translation:

> You're wrong! Kingdom Hearts is a heart that can erase any darkness. It's light!

However, I feel like this use of どんな+も with a regular noun is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second thought is correct; どんな + noun + も can be used to mean "any" or "any kind of".

> どんな誘惑にも負けません。
>   I will not give in to any kind of temptation.

You can use it with both nouns and verbs (in -て form). A common expression using this pattern with a verb is 「どんなことがあっても」, meaning "no matter what":

> どんなことがあってもあきらめない！
>   I'm not going to give up no matter what!

I also think it is more common to see this pattern with -でも rather than just -も.

> 安ければ、どんな携帯でもいい。
>   Any phone is fine as long as it's cheap.

Comment: So でも and も are interchangeable in this case? No difference at all?